# Android : Unable to draw line on canvas using a on click function

Tags: android, canvas

I am instantiating the canvas variable in the onCreate function and if i draw a line in onCreate function, it is displayed fine. However, if i draw the line in an onClick function of a button, it does not work. What could be the reason.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 153, 51));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
   }

    public void displayLine(View view) {
        canvas.drawLine(10, 20, 400, 500, paint);
    }
```

Comment: There is a lot of code missing here.  Where is your onClick handler?  Where is your canvas object stored? Where is displayLine called?

Comment: Which language is this ?

Comment: The button is assigned the onClick function of displayLine. I did not understand what you meany by the storage of canvas object. Can you elaborate. The strange thing is if i draw the line (above statement in the function) in the onCreate method itself, it draws the line fine. But when i move that statement to an onclick function of a button, it no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Not that I would necessarily do it this way... but have you tried adding an invalidate call? i.e.:

```
public void displayLine(View view) {
        canvas.drawLine(10, 20, 400, 500, paint);
        view.invalidate();
    }
```